# jConfirmation on top of dialog

Tags: javascript

I'm new to html& jquery. I'm having a dialog and while trying to close it, I need to ask a confirmation message, which should be displayed on top of the existing dialog. I tried using jconfirmation, but it comes up after closing the existing dialog. But I need the confirmation to come on top of the existing dialog. How can I do it?

```
$("#ref").load('myTest.html').dialog({
create:function(e,u) {
   // ETC
},
close:function(e,u){
  //ADD CODE TO SHOW CONFIRMATION ON TOP
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Dialog will fire close callback after it is closed. Try using beforeClose event. You should be able to use the same call back that you are using for close with it

```
$("#ref").load('myTest.html').dialog({
   create:function(e,u) {
      // ETC
   },
   beforeClose:function(e,u){
      //ADD CODE TO SHOW CONFIRMATION ON TOP
   }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Dialog#event-beforeClose